# How do I turn off loud alert from Safari?

Tags: safari

Safari occasionally rings a loud bell sound for unknown reason. I haven't been able to find a way to turn it off. Can anyone explain why it makes these sounds and how to get it to stop?

When I clicked POST YOUR QUESTION, Safari rang the bell again.

---

Answer to question: I am running OS X 10.9.1.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Check for 3rd party extensions you may have installed in Safari.

Specifically, the "[GMail Counter](http://elix14.altervista.org/)" for Safari has a bell ring sound effect to it when it detects new mail on Gmail.

Can't say it's *that specific extension* in question - but still, check your installed extensions and disable/re-enable them until you find the culprit.